# AWS CLI: Describe Network ACLs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, jmespath

I am having a bit of an issue with this command. I am trying to list out only the `egress` `ACL` rules, and just the rule number. So this is my command:

```
aws ec2 describe-network-acls --network-acl-ids acl-c324a5a4 --output text --query 'NetworkAcls[*].Entries[*].{RN:RuleNumber}' --filter Name=entry.rule-action,Values=allow Name=entry.egress,Values=true
```

The return of this is:

```
100
110
120
130
140
150
160
170
32767
100
110
120
130
140
150
160
170
32767
```

It is basically listing both egress and ingress rules. The egress and ingress rules have the same rule number. It also lists the *`DENY rule (32767)`, I would also like to avoid that.

Can anyone help me with this command where I want to list out only egress rule numbers?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so you want the *Egress* Rule Number which are allowed. You can do that using the following query:

```
aws ec2 describe-network-acls \
  --output text \
  --network-acl-ids acl-c324a5a4 \
  --query 'NetworkAcls[*].Entries[?(RuleAction==`allow` && Egress==`true`)].{RN:RuleNumber}'
```

You can read more about [Controlling Command Output from the AWS Command Line Interface](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html)

Comment: Right, so that's how you do it. Thanks very much! May I bother you with one last thing? How do I add to this query the Port Range? Say I have the rule on To and From port 20... how do I query for that specific port (including the allow && egress from before). Thanks!

Comment: Actually, no need. I should've tried before asking you for more help. Only had to do this: PortRange.To==`20`

Answer (score 2):

With the help of awk and grep we can get the list of the only Egress rules as shown below.

```
aws ec2 describe-network-acls --network-acl-ids acl-63092b1a  --query 'NetworkAcls[*].Entries[*].[Egress,RuleNumber]' --output text | grep -v False | awk {'print $2'} | grep -v '^$\|^\s*\#'
```

To filter results by the value of a specific field, use the JMESPath "?" operator. The following example query outputs only volumes in the us-west-2a availability zone:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-volumes --query 'Volumes[?AvailabilityZone==`us-west-2a`]'
```

[For More Information please go through this article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html)

Comment: Nice idea, using awk. Thanks. But you will probably agree with me that leveraging the correct using of the query string it looks much more professional - what do you think?

Comment: I agree with you @FelipeCaldas

Comment: Agreed... Minimizing technologies involved has many benefits - maintainability, security, host resource needs, etc.